# onClickListener on item inside RecyclerView on tablayout with viewpager

Tags: android, kotlin

i tried to have onClickListener on each item inside my recyclerview, but idk how to do so.
Heres my code:

**ViewPagerAdapter**

```
class ViewPagerAdapter(private val mContext: MainActivity, fm:FragmentManager): FragmentPagerAdapter(fm, BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT) {

    private val list: List<Fragment> = listOf(
        FragmentCredit(),
        FragmentDataPackage()
    )

    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return list.size
    }

    override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment {
        return list[position]
    }

    override fun getPageTitle(position: Int): CharSequence? {
        return when(position){
            0->"Package"
            else->"Packet Data"
        }
    }
}
```

**RecylerviewAdapter**

```
class RecyclerViewAdapterCredit(val listCredit: ArrayList<Credit>): RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapterCredit.RecycleViewHolder>() {

    inner class RecycleViewHolder(itemView: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){
        var packageName = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textviewCreditPackage)
        var packagePrice = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textviewCreditPrice)
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecycleViewHolder {
        val view: View = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_credit, parent, false)
        return RecycleViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecycleViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val item: Credit = listCredit[position]
        holder.packageName.text = item.packageName
        holder.packagePrice.text = item.packagePrice
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return listCredit.size
    }
```

**FragmentAdapter**

```
class FragmentCredit:Fragment() {
    lateinit var recycler: RecyclerView
    private val list = ArrayList<Credit>()
    private val adapter: RecyclerViewAdapterCredit = RecyclerViewAdapterCredit(list)
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState)
        val v: View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_credit, container, false)
        recycler = v.findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewCredit)
        val adapter = RecyclerViewAdapterCredit(list)
        recycler.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(activity, 2)
        recycler.adapter = adapter
        return v
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
}
```

I tried to show that fragment inside each tablayout with this

**MainActivity**

```
    viewPager.adapter = ViewPagerAdapter(this, supportFragmentManager)
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager)
```

main activity xml look like this

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/etNomor"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:autofillHints="phone"
        android:hint="@string/nomor_handphone"
        android:inputType="phone"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageviewContact"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:contentDescription="@string/this_is_a_image"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_contacts_24"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/etNomor"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/etNomor"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/etNomor"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/etNomor" />

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/Submit"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/etNomor"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/etNomor"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/imageviewContact"
        android:text="@string/submit"
        style="@style/sf.Reguler.text"
        android:background="@drawable/button_oval"
        android:textColor="@color/white"/>

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/etNomor"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/etNomor"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/Submit" />

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/tabLayout"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/tabLayout"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tabLayout" />
```

I read a few articles on google, but either its java or there's not someone make a guide for onClickListener inside rv on tablayout.

**Asking**

1. Where do i implements onClickListener event for this? in my recyclerview adapter or my fragment adapter?
2. Can i pass clicked items from that recyclerview to another activity when submit button not in list item from recyclerview? or should i just put submit button inside recyclerview?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a `onClickListener` on each row of the `RecyclerView` by storing the reference to the `itemView` and defining the `setOnClickListener` on it:

```
    inner class RecycleViewHolder(itemView: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        val view = itemView
        var packageName = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textviewCreditPackage)
        var packagePrice = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textviewCreditPrice)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecycleViewHolder, position: Int) {
        ...
        holder.view.setOnClickListener {
            // Handle your click event
        }
    }
```

Comment: i tried to make a simple toast on  setOnClickListener, and somehow i get error on context, tried to put context this, MainActivity, name of currently fragment, but it didt work at all. Can u make a simple example ty.